# Java - Missing first letter in every lines

Tags: java

I'm creating File Transfer program that will transfer a file to client. But when I transferred the file, It missing the first letter of every lines. What's wrong with my code?

I'm pretty new at java so I don't know what to do next. I've tried changing byte size but no help. What should I do?

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileSend;
        System.out.print("Type the path to the file to send >> ");
        fileSend = scan.nextLine();
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5467);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not bind to port 5467, Maybe address is already is use or you need to run as administrator");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Listening on port 5467");
        System.out.println("Waiting for the connection...");
        while (true) {
            File FileSend = null;
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            String login = dataIn.readUTF();
            String password = dataIn.readUTF();
            String result = "You credential is ";
            if (login.equals("1c18b5cdef8f9b4c5d6b2ad087265e597d1d4639337b73a04a335103c00ec64b") && password.equals("1c18b5cdef8f9b4c5d6b2ad087265e597d1d4639337b73a04a335103c00ec64b13d0b73358bfa8978dfaaf180565bcfecd3dc0631cda525920865145fb3fa131")) {
                result += "correct";
            } else {
                result += "incorrect";
            }
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
            try {
                dataOut.writeUTF(result);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("No such file or directory");
            }
            finally
            {
                FileSend = new File(fileSend);
                byte[] FileByteArray = new byte[(int) FileSend.length()];
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(FileSend);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("No such file or directory");
                    return;
                }
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                File myFile = new File (fileSend);
                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Sending " + fileSend + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
                os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

                os.flush();
                System.out.println("Done.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Socket socket = null;
        String PlainLogin;
        String FileOut;
        String PlainPassword;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the IP address of the server >> ");
        String host = scan.nextLine();
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, 5467);
        } catch (ConnectException | NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Refused, Have you run the server first?");
            return;
        }

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        System.out.println("Credential Required, Please login");
        System.out.print("Type your username >> ");
        PlainLogin = scan.next();
        System.out.print("Type your password >> ");
        PlainPassword = scan.next();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashInBytes = md.digest(PlainLogin.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : hashInBytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        String HashedLogin = sb.toString();

        byte[] hashInBytesP = md.digest(PlainPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        for (byte b : hashInBytesP) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        String HashedPassword = sb.toString();
        dataOut.writeUTF(HashedLogin);
        dataOut.writeUTF(HashedPassword);

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
        String str = dataIn.readUTF();
        if (str == "Your credential is incorrect") {
            System.out.println(str);
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Type any file name you want >> ");
            scan.nextLine();
            FileOut = scan.nextLine();

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(FileOut);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
            is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output.close();
            socket.close();
            dataIn.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to show full text like "Java", but it only show "ava"

Comment: Do you send UTF encoded data too? My wild guess is that the first byte is treated as BOM and eaten. Have a look at raw byte data that is incoming does it match the outgoing data from server.

Comment: try with this in loop   while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File is Serializable, so I would suggest you should simply try to send it directly via ObjectOutputStream / ObjectInputStream.

For example on Server side :

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
...
out.writeObject(yourFileObject);
```

And on Client :

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
...
File receivedFile = null;
try {
    receivedFile = (File) in.readObject();
}
catch (IOException e) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure *why* this happens exactly, but you shouldn't be using `DataInputStream` which "[lets an application read primitive Java data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)", but an `InputStreamReader` which "[is a bridge from byte streams to character streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/InputStreamReader.html)".

Also, you can wrap that reader into a `BufferedReader` which lets you read line by line, and you'll end up with something like

```
try (BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, UTF8));
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    reader.lines().forEach(writer::println);
}
```

for an upload, or

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outStream)) {
    Files.lines().forEach(writer::println);
}
```

for download.